# Downcasting procedure

Tags: c++, downcast

Can anyone please explain me if its alright to downcast this way or we SHOULD use an explicit type cast for it?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class base {
public:
    virtual void func() { cout<<"Base \n"; }
            void fun()  { cout<<"fun"; }
};

class derived1 : public base {
public:
            void func() { cout<<"Derived 1\n"; };
            void fun()  { cout<<"fun1"; }
};

class derived2 : public derived1 {
public:
            void func() { cout<<"Derived 2\n"; }
            void fun()  { cout<<"fun2"; }
};


int main()
{
    base * var = new derived1;

    ((base *) var)-> fun();
    ((derived1 *) var)-> fun();
    ((derived2 *) var)-> fun(); 

    // How does this work?
}
```

Comment: you are missing `virtual` in `derived1` for `func`.

Comment: @40two in my experience it's not really required, a good compiler will understand that it's already virtual seeing it from the base class's declaration

Comment: @40two It isn't necessary, and it would work in the same way even if I add it.

Comment: looks like a design flaw, the real question is why do you need this ?

Comment: `((derived2 *) var)-> fun();` win or fail, I fail to judge. Is the "how does this work" question about that line or what? Have you really intentionally exploited your compiler features, or did you do it by accident?

Comment: It is an exam question, it exploited me and the compiler features, both.

Comment: @fritzone A *compliant* compiler hides, not overrides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((base *) var)-> fun();` and `((derived1 *) var)-> fun();` are *valid*, but not good practice. You should use `C++` style casting ( `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`..) instead of `c-style` casting.

`((derived2 *) var)-> fun();` is **not valid**, as `var` is not really of class `derived2`. It will fail if you use `dynamic_cast` for casting. But here it works because of *object alignment* in `C++`. In the code section, normally the derived members are laid, following the base members, and in the sequence that they are defined. So, `derived1::fun` and `derived2::fun` will be started from same offset in this case, and hence calling it works. although the object after casting to `derived2*` is invalid, it works since `fun` does not access any member of the class. But this behavior is unpredictable, and **must not rely on this or use this kind of code**.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here `base * var = new derived1;` you are up-casting.

Second, It's safer to use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) for the down-castings.

```
derived1 *d1 = dynamic_cast<derived1*>(var);
if(d1) d1->fun();
derived2 *d2 = dynamic_cast<derived2*>(var); // will return NULL
if(d2) d2->fun();
```

Comment: You know there is a big problem in a piece of code when your answer to a question about it is "I recommend to use dynamic_cast"...

Comment: @Griwes I'm not a native speaker, you think that "recommend" should be removed?

Comment: @40two I get it, I am just wondering if my way of downcasting is acceptable or not, thought it is working but is that acceptable?

Comment: I think that the answer here is to tell OP how he should write his code in the first place, not letting him believe that what he does makes any kind of sense.